# AlertDialog won't show in onCreate method

Tags: android, dialog, oncreate

So I want to ask a user their name before continuing the build of an activity. Most of the activity is populated dynamically so it seems like this should be easy. For some reason, the Dialog never appears though. I've tried everything and the only thing I can think of is: Perhaps it doesn't like being in the onCreate method? It doesn't seem like this should be an issue though since it's literally the last method being called in onCreate. Check it out and let me know what you see:

**onCreate method:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    initializeHotels();
    FIRST_TURN = true;

    clearOldBoard();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_board);
    setUpBoardGUI();

    setOnPlayerSetUpEventListener(new onPlayerSetUpEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlayerSetUp(){
            prepForFirstTurn();
        }
    }); 

    startGameDialog();
}
```

**And the startGameDialog method:**

```
public void startGameDialog(){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.AppBaseTheme);

    AlertDialog.Builder startGameDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctw);
    startGameDialog.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.whats_your_name));

    LinearLayout dialogLayout = new LinearLayout(context);

        final EditText newName = new EditText(context);
        newName.setText("");

        Button submit = new Button(context);
        OnClickListener onClick = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                GameBoardActivity.NAME = newName.toString();
                setUpPlayers();

            }
        };
        submit.setOnClickListener(onClick);

    dialogLayout.addView(newName);
    dialogLayout.addView(submit);

    startGameDialog.setView(dialogLayout);
    Dialog dialog = startGameDialog.create();
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setCancelable(false);

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `create` method return an instance of [`AlertDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#create%28%29)

Instead of initializing it to the Dialog when you call the create method of the AlertDialog

```
Dialog dialog = startGameDialog.create();
dialog.show();
```

pass it to the AlertDialog

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = startGameDialog.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

use the currents activity context rather than using the whole application contex.t

```
Context context = Your_activity.this;
```

Comment: Sorry. This is a "no go". Especially since I use that same code design for other dialogs elsewhere in the program and it executes flawlessly. (Tried anyways and it doesn't work).

Comment: @JRadtheBad it is working?? but its not working in your current activity?

Comment: The `AlertDialog` that won't display is the code you see above. Elsewhere in the program, I use almost the exact same code and the dialog boxes show up fine. It is only in this specific situation that the dialog doesn't display.

Comment: @JRadtheBad have you tried Context context = Your_activity.this;

Comment: @JRadtheBad instead of using the entire application context try to use the context of your activity.

Comment: Wow... I'm surprised, but that worked. How come that worked but `getApplicationContext();" didn't?

Comment: @JRadtheBad because you are using the entire application context instead of using the current activity context.